# Serial Port: Different answers from device

Tags: c#, c++, qt, serial-port

I have a little problem with translating my code. I'm trying to make some relays (set on a custom made PCB) to turn on and off while I press a button.
The problem is I made the code that's doing it (so it is turning on and off depending on my actions) but I also need to read the answer from the machine. The point is I had an older version of the code written in C#, and when sending the code through that program, I get the OK answer, while using the new version of the code written in C++, I get only the first letter of the answer. 
I was following this using a serial port monitor to see what the machine sends back, and I had the same result (is not like my code only reads one letter). So, the point is: the C# code is getting the full answer ("AWOK11") while the C++ code gets only the first letter of it ("A").
C# Code done in SharpDevelop and C++ code done in Qt Creator.

C++ code:

```
QSerialPort portverf;
portverf.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
portverf.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
portverf.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
portverf.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
portverf.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
portverf.setPortName("COM41");
portverf.open();
port.write(command);
QString result = portverf.readAll();
```

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `QIODevice::readAll()` reads all available data from the device. If there was only an `A` available, it will return an `A`. It won't wait for additional characters. Since you read right after writing, reading only the first character is to be expected.

Comment: I have 4 different machines that are connected to the PC. I am trying to make the program recognise each device alone. What do you suggest me to do? Should sending the command at the start of the program and reading later do the trick?

Comment: @Alex Since you don't have flow control, the problem can be a bit tricky. As you said, adding a delay can work (at 9600 baud, you must wait at least 1ms per byte). You have to take into account the possible reaction time of the device. Another way is fixed length message ; if you need 6 bytes, you read until you get 6 bytes. You can also have an end marker, e.g. read until you get a `\0`. You decide what is best for you.

Comment: Actually, the device only sends back one byte when reading after sending the command. I will create a configuration file that will contain all the ports and how they are assigned and if the ports won't be the same, the program will search for them again. It will be like a one-time setup. I think that's the best (and also easiest) solution out of 'em all. Thanks a lot :D